# What does the symbol * after a type in C#?

Tags: c#, parameters, unsafe

I'm new in C# and what I learned at school it's really poor. Last week I came to the same problem, I didn't know what the ? means after a name type in C#. I could find the answer, then again what does "??" means in a expression, I'm really frustrated.

**In this case the star (*) what is telling me about the incoming parameter? (I'm into an unsafe code block)**

I'll really thanked if you give me some quick guides about this things in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` [after a type determines a pointer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) There's a good chance that you may never even need to use this.

---

`?` [after a type says that it is nullable.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) See below:

```
int? a = null;
int b = null; //Compile error
```

---

`??` [is the null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). Basically it will give you the right-hand side value if the left-hand side is null.

```
object a = null;
object b = new Object();
object c = a ?? b;
// 'c' is 'b' because 'a' was null.
```

---

I hope that answers your questions. I couldn't tell if you were asking about all of these or only the `*`.

Answer (score 1):

'*' means that it is a pointer, much liker pointers in C. You will very rarely encounter these in C# code.

Answer (score 0):

that's  how you can  declare pointer type, you better read [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Pointers are In an unsafe context